# JS/HTML 5 framework for a single ranking page

Tags: javascript, html, frameworks

I'm developing a single page full of reference links, similar to a browser favorite 'Yellow Page', and I need to impelment a ranking function to:

1. Record the click count on each  tag
2. Dynamically sort the list according to the access count

Please help advise whether there's any JS library / HTML5 framework to achieve this?

Comment: found something similar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515877/omniture-is-it-possible-to-count-number-of-clicks-per-special-tagged-link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need any frameworks for such task.

You need to create array of objects.
Each object has obj.link and obj.counter.
Than generate the list dynamically using sort() with obj.counter.

Speaking about frameworks, AngularJS will easily manage such functionality.